# Post XML with dashed element names using RestSharp

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, webservice-client, restsharp

I am trying to post some XML data with RestSharp. The web service API that I am posting to expects XML data that has the following structure:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rootElement>
   <first-child></first-child>
   <second-child></second-child>
<rootElement/>
```

I also have a class that I want to serialize to the required XML and which I will attach to the post request via `request.AddObject()`. Here is my class:

```
public class MyRootElement
{
    public string firstchild { get; set; }
    public string secondchild { get; set; }
}
```

**Now, here is my problem:** How do I get RestSharp to serialize my class so that the dashes are inserted into the names of the XML elements? Currently, the web service API I am posting to is refusing the request because it doesn't recognize the XML I am posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write an `ISerializer` implementation that does what you want (probably working with .NET's XmlSerializer), and register it with `RestClient.XmlSerializer = new YourSerializer();`